# onClick.invoke is not the same as clicking on a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Coming from other visual languages; I did notice that Unity does not follow the same inner workings.

I have a UI with a button; when you press it, the name of the button tell a function which panel has to become visible; in this way I can hide and show various panels, based on which button is pressed, and not worry about setting up each button in the UI.

Now, this works if you use the UI; because the eventsystem is able to intercept the pushed button and store the name of the button itself; but if you do the same via onClick.Invoke; this won't work.

The function that the button calls, is called correctly; but the eventsystem has no clue about the name of the calling button, because no button was called in the UI.

```
// this end up with the variable raising a null exception, when called 
// from the onClick.Invoke()
string buttonname = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
```

The expectation wa that the onClick.Invoke will have the same effect of the click/tap on the UI, but it is not the case. Is there any workaround for this? I would like to call functions that I call via buttons, but I rely on the names of the buttons to do certain operations.

I can change the functions to work around this limitation, but before doing so, I want to be sure that there is no other way to actually do that via code only.

Comment: perhaps you would like to look into and overwrite the IPointerClickHandler. It has a eventData param that has the clicked objects name.

Comment: I see, so this is how it works. In VC++ for example, you don't have to worry about that; since the click event is based on the button controller (and any other controller that implement it); which means that you can't just simulate a button press, without trigger every single code path triggered by phisically pressing the button. Unity approach is probably different, I will look into that handler (although it would help to see the original implementation)

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about the Question. If you want to get name of the button that is calling the onClick function. then why don't you just use the onclick button to return `this.name`?

Anyway you're confusing yourself Between MethodBase.Invoke and MonoBehaviour.Invoke to UnityEvent.Invoke. Currently you're using the UnityEvent.Invoke.

If you want to use the other simply use the respected namespace first.

For MethodBase.Invoke that you were saying it is in the Reflection namespace.

`using System.Reflection;`

```
 private Action myAction = ()=>{};

 void Start()
 {
    System.Type ourType = this.GetType(); 

    MethodInfo mi= ourType.GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (mi!= null){
        myAction = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, mi);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; to clarify, I am used to other visual tools; when you invoke the event on a button for example, you pass the button name and whatever event is triggered by that button, it will be performed via code. In Unity I can't do this, because the button name get passed to the event system only if you press it.